# Ansible shell one line syntax not working

Tags: ansible

is it possible to write the shell command in one line ?

```
- shell: my command
  register: var
  run_once: true
```

this work

```
- shell: "my command" register=var run_once=true
```

this does not work

Answer (score 1):

Shell is a one-to-one comparison to running the command yourself. From [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html?highlight=shell):

> The `shell` module takes the command name followed by a list of
>   space-delimited arguments.

So `my_command register=var run_once=true` would be correct if `my_command` runs that way when you run it in your local shell.

While you didn't ask about it, it's worth noting that it looks like you're trying to add parameters to the `shell` module that don't exist, so the first example you provided would have to use the `args` parameter:

```
- name: Execute my command in a remote shell
  shell: my_command
  args:
    register: var
    run_once: true
```

Documented examples of `shell` are [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html?highlight=shell#examples)